# dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using JMSPaymentCoreBundle and JMSPaymentPaypalBundle.

It worked well before,but now I have to change my config.yml for new Bundle(FOSMessageBundle)

I have to stop using 'auto_mapping' and  use 'entity_managers' instead

```
doctrine:
    dbal:

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
#       auto_mapping: true
        entity_managers:
            FOSUserBundle: ~
            FOSMessageBundle: ~
```

However after this changes .

```
 The service "payment.plugin_controller" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager"
```

this error happens.

I think changes in config.yml causes this trouble.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the error, you need to define an entity manager named `default`. In your case, the overall syntax is just wrong, see my example.

In config.yml:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default: # that's the name of the entity manager
                connection: default # you need to define the default connection
                mappings: 
                    FOSUserBundle: ~
                    FOSMessageBundle: ~
```

I'd advise you to read the documentations about ["Databases and Doctrine"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) and ["How to work with Multiple Entity Managers and Connections"](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)